# Doctrine ORM not returning the expected result

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am using a Doctrine ORM with Zend Framework 2
I am trying to run a simple query through it. It's not returning the expected output.

```
    $resultObject = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT max(u.displayId) FROM Test\Entity\TestMe u WHERE u.product = 12); 
    $resultDisplayId =$resultObject->getSingleScalarResult();
```

The above query should give me 1 but it returns 8.
 Is there something to do with Cache?
 Please suggest.
Thanks!!

Comment: We need to see a database dump to help you. Also, if possible, paste here the code of your entity.

Comment: Solved!! I got it. I had one more object which is running in a loop and at the same time calling these lines..
Thanks